# Choosing values in a strong induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

The sequence s0,s1,s2... is defined by s0=1 and for all integers n>0,
$s(n)=s(⌊n/2⌋)+s(⌊2n/5⌋) + n.$
Prove, using strong induction, that  S(n) > 4n for all integers n>=3.

To my knowledge, I only have to prove a single base case n=3. What I am not sure about is how to do the induction step, specifically the following:

Let k be an integer $k >= ? $. Suppose that for all integers $m$, where $0<=m<k$....

I am not sure how to determine what value '?' should be for k, and also what dictates why the lower range for m is 0 and not something else?

Here are the first 8 values of the sequence for reference:

S1= S0 + S0 + 1 = 3

S2= S1 + S1 + 2 = 8

S3= S1 + S2 + 3 = 14

S4= S2 + S2 + 4 = 20

S5= S2 + S3 + 5 = 27

S6= S3 + S4 + 6 = 40

S7= S3 + S4 + 7 = 41

S8= S4 + S5 + 8 = 55

Comment: You assume that the claim is correct for all values $n$ with $3\le n< k$ and you proof the claim for $n=k$. ($k\ge 3$ is an arbitary integer).

Comment: @Peter So why not have k >=2 then?

Comment: Because the base case is $n=3$ here. In fact, it should be $k\ge 4$, sorry for that error.

Comment: @Peter Why is the base case 4?

Comment: The claim is false for $n=1$ and $n=2$. The first case, for which the claim is true, is $n=3$. Therefore, it is the base case. But the induction step is : $k\ge 4$, assume truth for $3\le n\ <k$ and show the truth for $n=k$.

Comment: So, start with $n=3$. Prove that the claim is true for $n=4$. Now, assume the claim is true for $n=3$ AND $n=4$. Prove that the claim is true for $n=5$ and so on. The first case after the base case is $n=4$, therefore $k\ge 4$. If you dislike this, you can also start with $k=3$. Then, you assume that the claim is true for $3\le n\le k$ and show it for $n=k+1$.